how to implement regex in search bar for ecommerce site (dynamic search)
i want that if somebody search query in app then if the query is mis spelled then it will automatically understand the key
i try to do it with regex but if i do search("back") so according to my requirement it should work but it doesn't
and regex patter is this("(?i)." + query + ".")  that i am using

Do you mean you want to perform a case insensitive search?

Please provide example inputs that should match and example inputs that should not match.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can try below options -

Fuzzy query - Returns documents that contain terms similar to the search term, as measured by a Levenshtein edit distance.

Suggester - Suggests similar looking terms based on a provided text. In case of spelling mistake it will suggest right term.

You can also give a try with semantic search, Which will pick correct context in case you have spelling mistake.


